# How to change link button text in gridview at runtime in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row, gridviewrow

In my gridview some rows are already presents. Gridview have one column containing link button. But when I add new row in gridview I want to change the text of that link button for that new row only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your gridview events, you can access specific row attributes in the event handlers.

For example, RowCreated:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**GridView doesn't support inserting a new row like the way we update/Delete a row.This means that There is NO such BuiltIn functionality for Inserting a row. Obviously there are workarounds for this problem.** You may say there is a `RowCreated` Event of GridView, however this event is raised when GridView renders itself and is seen closely related to `RowDataBound`.

The easiest way to get hands on inserting a new row is using the DetailsView.

**`DetailsView:`**

Add a CommandField inside `<Fields>` section of Details view as below:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"   
            AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID"   
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">  
            <Fields>  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID"             
                    SortExpression="CustomerID" />  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName"/>  
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName"/>    
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowEditButton="True"   
                    ShowInsertButton="True" />  
            </Fields>  
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

You also need to have a **`SqlDataSource`** control as below:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"   
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"   
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customers] ([CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName]) VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName, @ContactName)" >
<InsertParameters>  
                <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="String" />  
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />  
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactName" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>  
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

However, still if you want to use grid View only using some workarounds, below link is worth seeing: 
http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx